# Iterating through ZonedDateTime interval in Duration steps

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

**Problem**

Given a start and end timestamp and a duration I'd like to iterate through that time interval in steps of the duration. The duration should be specified in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) notation. Daylight saving time should be considered depending on the timezone.

Example code:

```
// start/end at switch from summer to winter time
ZonedDateTime startTimestamp = ZonedDateTime.of( LocalDateTime.of(2018, 10, 28, 0, 0), ZoneId.of("CET"));
ZonedDateTime endTimestamp = startTimestamp.plusHours(5);

Duration duration = Duration.parse( "PT1H");
while( startTimestamp.isBefore(endTimestamp)) {
    System.out.println( startTimestamp);
    startTimestamp = startTimestamp.plus( duration);
}
```

Which results in:

```
2018-10-28T00:00+02:00[CET]
2018-10-28T01:00+02:00[CET]
2018-10-28T02:00+02:00[CET]
2018-10-28T02:00+01:00[CET]
2018-10-28T03:00+01:00[CET]
```

The problem is that this works as long as the duration is days at max. From the Duration parser documentation:

> There are then four sections, each consisting of a number and a suffix. The sections have suffixes in ASCII of "D", "H", "M" and "S" for days, hours, minutes and seconds, accepted in upper or lower case.

But the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) standard specifies that a duration might also be in months and years.

> Durations define the amount of intervening time in a time interval and
>   are represented by the format P[n]Y[n]M[n]DT[n]H[n]M[n]S or P[n]W

**Question**

How do you properly iterate in ISO 8601 duration steps through a ZonedDateTime interval considering calendar elements of Week, Month, Year?

Example for Month:

```
Start: 01.01.2018
End: 01.01.2019
```

I'd like to get every 1st of each month. Specifying `P1M` as duration throws of course this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: 
Text cannot be parsed to a Duration
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with date related fields (years, months and days), you must use a `java.time.Period`. Example:

```
ZonedDateTime startTimestamp = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0), ZoneId.of("CET"));
ZonedDateTime endTimestamp = startTimestamp.plusMonths(5);

Period period = Period.parse("P1M");
while (startTimestamp.isBefore(endTimestamp)) {
    System.out.println(startTimestamp);
    startTimestamp = startTimestamp.plus(period);
}
```

This prints:

> 2018-01-01T00:00+01:00[CET]
>   2018-02-01T00:00+01:00[CET]
>   2018-03-01T00:00+01:00[CET]
>   2018-04-01T00:00+02:00[CET]
>   2018-05-01T00:00+02:00[CET]

Unfortunately, `java.time` has divided ISO8601 durations in  2 classes, where `Period` works with date-based fields, while `Duration` works with time-based fields.

### Alternative

If you don't mind adding a dependency to your application, you can use the threeten extra lib: http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/

It contains the [class `PeriodDuration`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html), that encapsulates both a `Period` and a `Duration`, so both "P1M" or "PT1H" will work:

```
// this works
PeriodDuration period = PeriodDuration.parse("P1M");

// this too
PeriodDuration period = PeriodDuration.parse("PT1H");
```

And the `plus` method can receive a `PeriodDuration`, because it also implements `TemporalAmount`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a do while loop.

```
ZonedDateTime startTimestamp = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 4, 20, 12, 10), ZoneId.of("CET"));
ZonedDateTime endTimestamp = startTimestamp.plusHours(5);

Duration duration = Duration.parse("PT1H");
do {
    System.out.println(startTimestamp.toLocalTime());
    startTimestamp = endTimestamp.plus(duration);
} while (startTimestamp.isBefore(endTimestamp));
```

You have to re-initialize the `startTimeStamp` with adding duration in to the end timestamp.

Comment: Won’t that make sure you only get one iteration if the duration is non-negative? Also it doesn’t answer the question. The question was “How do you properly iterate in ISO 8601 duration steps through a ZonedDateTime interval considering calendar elements of **Week, Month, Year**?” (my emphasis)